# why if comparison doesn't work in java

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison, assign

I am making a Hash Table in java. 
In searching function, I am doing some comparison in IF statement. but it is not doing any comparison.

here's is some part of my code.

---

```
while (table[pos]!=null) {
        if (table[pos]==key) {
            System.out.println("SEARCH "+key+" at INDEX "+home);
            return;
        }
        else {pos=h(home+p(i));
        i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Failed to find "+key+".");
    return;
}
```

---

It doesn't work even when table[pos] and key are the same!
but I add very simple assigning variable to another one. It work! I don't know why it works. I wanna know it xD

```
   while (table[pos]!=null) {
        int x = table[pos];
        if (x==key) {
            System.out.println("SEARCH "+key+" at INDEX "+home);
            return;
        }
        else {pos=h(home+p(i));
        i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Failed to find "+key+".");
    return;
}
```

Comment: you might need to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for us to now what your exact problem is (currently it seems unclear), including input, actual output and expected output aswell as a tiny executable example demonstrating the problem itself. Proper code formating also helps identifying problems better :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not doing any comparison"? What happened when you debugged it line by line?

Comment: table is undefined. Add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7):

Well, if `table[pos]` and `key` are both `Integer` (and `table[pos]` must be a reference type, since you are comparing it to `null` in the `while` statement), they should be compared with `equals`, not with `==`, since two different `Integer` objects may have the same `int` value.

When you assign `table[pos]` to the `int` variable `x`, it is un-boxed to a primitive value.

Now, when you compare the `int` `x` to the `Integer` `key`, the `key` is also un-boxed to an `int`, and `int` comparison works with `==`.

This can be demonstrated by the following short example:

```
Integer i1 = 300;
Integer i2 = 300;
System.out.println (i1 == i2);
int i3 = i1;
System.out.println (i3 == i2);
```

which outputs:

```
false
true
```

The code code would be:

```
while (table[pos] != null) {
    if (table[pos].equals(key)) {
        System.out.println("SEARCH "+key+" at INDEX "+home);
        return;
    } else {
        pos = h(home + p(i));
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Failed to find "+key+".");
```

Comment: actually not really. You should use both `==` and `equals`; first one acting as a faster check. an btw this is what `HashMap` does internally too: `((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))`

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two objects with `==`, you check if both of these references point to the same place in the memory, while using `==` with primitives simply checks if values are the same. To correctly check equation of values inside two `Integers` you should use `equals()` method.

In your second example you used unboxing from `Integer` to `int` so it checked values as you expected it to do. In the first one you compared if both values point to the same place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct way is to use *both* just like `HashMap` does for example, this way we will always be sure. This is for example how `HashMap` does it internally:

```
if(((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) ...
```

So in your case it would be:

```
if ((table[pos] == key) || (key != null && (table[pos].equals(key)))) {
```